# How to have sas log in both external location and sas enterprise guide

Tags: logging, sas, external, enterprise-guide

I am using sas eg 5.1 version. right now I am routing my log details to an external file(text document) for record keeping. But while developing a code, I want the error log to appear in the sas egp log window also, so that it makes debugging faster and easy

**So my question is how to have sas log details in both sas egp and in external file at the same time**

I tried searching for it, but could not get the details.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'in session' programmable option to write the log to multiple destinations.  However a decent 'hack' is to simply read your external log and write out to your session log as follows:

```
/* write to external log */
filename tmp "C:\temp\mylog.txt";
proc printto log=tmp; run;

/* now run your SAS code */
%put NOTE: processing lots of juicy SAS statements;

/* once done, return to normal logging */
proc printto log=log; run; 

/* print previous log to current session */
data _null_;
  infile tmp;
  input; list;
run;

/* close filename */
filename tmp clear;
```

To ensure you always write the log out / get it back, you could even split the above into the following locations:

[image: EG dialog box showing custom code to run before & after task]

**Other options:**

An admin can [enable logging](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-switch-on-workspace-logging.html) on the application (workspace) server. This will capture all logs, from all users - which does have performance and storage implications!  Steps as follows:

- Navigate to: [sasconfig]\Lev1\SASApp\WorkspaceServer
- Rename logconfig.xml to logconfig.xml.orig
- Rename Logconfix.trace.xml to
  logconfig.xml
- Restart the object spawner

Another approach, as proposed by @Quentin / @Reeza in this (very similar) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609395/sas-print-to-log-and-view-live-log-window-simultaneously), is to use the `-altlog` option at SAS invocation.

Finally, if it suits, you could look at enabling the EG [project log](http://www.dummies.com/software/other-software/turning-on-the-project-log-in-sas-enterprise-guide/).

Comment: Thank you RawFocus very much. It is very helpful to me

Comment: Glad to hear it, and welcome to stackoverflow! If you are happy with an answer on this site, the best response is always to mark an answer as accepted - see tick mark above and to the left :-)