# Retrieving the SAS log without using a file

Tags: logging, sas, sas-macro

I'd like to send my SAS log via email.
I found a lot of documentation to do it by saving the log on the disk.
I can't use this kind of approach because of file system restrictions.
Would it be possible to redirect my log to a macro variable and put it in the email?

Comment: Macro vars have length restrictions such as 64k characters. PROC PRINTTO will redirect log to a specific text file and location and then you can email it as an attachment.

Comment: In short, you could write your log to a text file then load it into a macro variable, but it's not recommended (how would you deal with CRLFs / the 64k restriction etc).  You DO have permission to write files to your work directory.. You can also use  `filename tmp temp;`

Comment: What about `filename email`?

Comment: Thanks and sorry dears, I'm new in SAS and in stack**overflow** too.
I'm going to accept the answer (if I can).

Comment: Finally Allan Bowe was right. I have permissions but I was using (I suppose!) SAS steps that can only read/write file into a Windows file system (DM instead of PROC PRINTTO).
My SAS pgm runs on a Unix server.
Probably this misled me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I don't think you can redirect the log to a macro variable. But you always have write access to the work directory, so you can write it there, like:

```
proc printto log="%sysfunc(pathname(work))/mylog.log" new ;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, sad news!

Comment: @cinghio - you should accept this answer.  For more details you can also review:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115153/how-to-have-sas-log-in-both-external-location-and-sas-enterprise-guide

Comment: Everything is fine now. I managed to write the file, I don't need "in-memory" log anymore.
Anyway thanks for your help, now I know a new thing about SAS log.